# Extract correct creation date from avi file

Tags: file, date, delphi, extract, avi

I am using Delphi 10 and Windows 10 Home Edition 64-bit.  I have a video file called MVI_0640.AVI.  The date shown in the File Explorer is 15/04/04 which corresponds to the Media Created Date in the Properties window.

I am using the following code to extract dates.

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  ADate: TDateTime;
  FlHandle: integer;
  MyData: TWin32FindData;
  FlTime: TFileTime;
  MySysTime: TSystemTime;
begin
  {get date using GetCreationTime}
  ADate := TFile.GetCreationTime(FlName);
  Memo1.Lines.Add('GetCreationTime ' + DateToStr(ADate));

  {get date using FileGetDate}
  FlHandle := FileOpen(FlName,fmOpenRead);
  ADate := FileDateToDateTime(FileGetDate(FlHandle));
  FileClose(FlHandle);
  Memo1.Lines.Add('FileGetDate ' + DateToStr(ADate));

  {get date using FindFirstFile}
  FindFirstFile(PChar(FlName), MyData);

  FlTime := MyData.ftCreationTime;
  FileTimeToSystemTime(FlTime, MySysTime);
  ADate := SystemTimeToDateTime(MySysTime);
  Memo1.Lines.Add('ftCreationTime ' + DateToStr(ADate));

  FlTime := MyData.ftLastAccessTime;
  FileTimeToSystemTime(FlTime, MySysTime);
  ADate := SystemTimeToDateTime(MySysTime);
  Memo1.Lines.Add('ftLastAccessTime ' + DateToStr(ADate));

  FlTime := MyData.ftLastWriteTime;
  FileTimeToSystemTime(FlTime, MySysTime);
  ADate := SystemTimeToDateTime(MySysTime);
  Memo1.Lines.Add('ftLastWriteTime ' + DateToStr(ADate));

end;
```

The result looks like this:

[image]

None of the dates reflect the Media Created Date. How can I extract it?

In answer to Tom Brunberg’s comment I attach an extract of the file taken with a hex editor.
[image]

Comment: Hi Rudi, the creation date resides inside the AVI file as metadata. I am not sure if you can use the shell api to access the information.

Comment: An avi file is a RIFF file. Search on specifications of the formats. E.g. : https://www.sno.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/TagNames/RIFF.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found an answer to my question.  Probably not very elegant or save but it does it's job.  I tested it on more than 100 files and it worked without a problem.  Here is my answer:

```
function TForm1.GetAviMediaCreationDate(AFile: string): TDateTime;
var
  FS: TFileStream;
  NumOfChar: integer;
  i,d: integer;
  ABuffer: array of byte;
  AStr: string;
  DateStr: string;
  sdp: integer; //start date position
  dn,mn,yn: integer; //used to encode date
begin
  sdp := 0;
  FS := TFileStream.Create(AFile,fmOpenRead);
  NumOfChar := 400;
  SetLength(ABuffer,NumOfChar);
  FS.Read(Pointer(ABuffer)^, NumOfChar);
  {find IDIT}
  for i := 0 to NumOfChar-1 do
  begin
    AStr := Char(ABuffer[i]) +
            Char(ABuffer[i+1]) +
            Char(ABuffer[i+2]) +
            Char(ABuffer[i+3]);
    if AStr = 'IDIT' then sdp := i+7;
  end;
  {extract date}
  for d := 1 to 24 do
  DateStr := DateStr + Char(ABuffer[sdp+d]);
  {assemble TDateTime}
  //123456789 123456789 123456789
  //Sun Jun 28 10:13:39 2015
  dn := StrToInt(Copy(DateStr,9,2));
  mn := IndexText(Copy(DateStr,5,3),ShortMonthNames)+1;
  yn := StrToInt(Copy(DateStr,21,4));
  Result := EncodeDate(yn, mn, dn);
  FS.Free;
end;

procedure TForm1.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  ADate: TDateTime;
begin
  ADate := GetAviMediaCreationDate(FlName);
  Memo1.Lines.Add(DateToStr(ADate));
end;
```

Comment: Heh, heh. Speak about coincidences. Just a few minutes between.

Answer (score 3):

The date you are looking for is in a chunk called `IDIT`. It is referred to e.g. in [this document](https://www.eden-foundation.org/products/code/film_date_stamp/index.html)

Structure is simple, (sample data from a file of mine):

```
chunk id:     IDIT  // 4 ASCII chars
chunk length: 0000001A // 26 bytes
chunk data:   Sun Aug 31 12:15:22 2008/n/0 // date as ascii string
```

The structure of an `AVI` file is [outlined by Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/directshow/avi-riff-file-reference),  as follows, with addition of the location of IDIT chunk if present

```
RIFF ('AVI '
      LIST ('hdrl'
            'avih'(<Main AVI Header>)
            LIST ('strl'
                  'strh'(<Stream header>)
                  'strf'(<Stream format>)
                  [ 'strd'(<Additional header data>) ]
                  [ 'strn'(<Stream name>) ]
                  ...
                 )
             ... (note, if present, the IDIT chunk appears here)
           )
      LIST ('movi'
            {SubChunk | LIST ('rec '
                              SubChunk1
                              SubChunk2
                              ...
                             )
               ...
            }
            ...
           )
      ['idx1' (<AVI Index>) ]
     )
```

The above mentioned document also outlines the various structures.

Sample data:
[image]

A function to get the date (if present in the file) could be as follows:

```
// Note! finetuned to search only the main TLIST 'hdrl' 
function GetOriginalDate(AviFileName: TFileName; out s: string): boolean;
type
  TChunkId = array[0..3] of AnsiChar;

  TChunk = record
    chid: TChunkId;
    size: cardinal;
    form: TChunkId;
  end;
var
  fs: TFileStream;
  Root: TChunk;
  Chnk: TChunk;
  Done: boolean;
  Date: ansistring;
  endpos: integer;
begin
  s := 'not found';
  Done := False;
  result := False;

  fs:= TFileStream.Create(AviFileName, fmOpenRead or fmShareDenyWrite);

  try
    fs.Read(Root, SizeOf(Root));
    if Root.chid <> 'RIFF' then exit;
    if Root.form <> 'AVI ' then exit;

    fs.Read(Chnk, SizeOf(TChunk)); // main LIST
    if Chnk.chid <> 'LIST' then exit;
    if Chnk.form <> 'hdrl' then exit;

    endpos := fs.Position + Chnk.size;
    repeat
      fs.Read(Chnk, SizeOf(TChunk));
      if Chnk.chid = 'IDIT' then
      begin
        fs.Seek(-4, TSeekOrigin.soCurrent);
        SetLength(Date, Chnk.size);
        fs.Read(Date[1], Length(Date));
        s := Date;
        Done := True;
      end
      else
        fs.Seek(Chnk.size-4, TSeekOrigin.soCurrent);
    until Done or (fs.Position > endpos);

  finally
    fs.Free;
  end;
end;
```

To call it, for example:

```
procedure TForm1.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  s: string;
begin
  GetOriginalDate('F:\My Video\2008-08-31\MVI_1279.AVI', s);
  Memo1.Lines.Add(s);
end;
```

And result in Memo1

```
Sun Aug 31 12:15:22 2008
```

Comment: Any chance to give a link to some sample code in Delphi?

Comment: Aren't metadata chunks expected in their own INFO top level chunk? Your screenshot even shows the INFO chunk. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_Interchange_File_Format#Use_of_the_INFO_chunk

Comment: No, sorry @Rudi I don't have such a link (and neither anything I could post now). But if you search SO for `read riff` something may come up. Can you confirm the existence of the `IDIT` tags in your files and that they look similar, that is the date and time is in same format?

Comment: @Amigo I guess it would be reasonable, but the more I look at various docs about `RIFF` the more it seems to be modified with various vendors own ideas of how it should be. But as you refer to my image, I'll do so also: You can clearly see that the `IDIT` tag is not in the `INFO` chunk, and no, there's no other `INFO` tag before either.

Comment: Rudi, the doc that @Sertac refers to also lists another tag as related to `DateTimeOriginal` (same as `IDIT`) and that is `DTIM`. I don't see that in any of my files, but I just thought I should mention it as a possible deviation from what I say in my answer. Also, I don't know whether such a tag would show up `Media Created Date` in Windows Explorer.

Comment: @TomBrunberg. Yes, the IDIT tag is in my file (I have added a copy of an extract to my question) and it shows the correct date.  I will now have to find a way to extract it.